# val3dity installation problem on Ubuntu 18.04 - Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES GMP_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: cmake, installation, ubuntu-18.04, cgal, gmp

I tried to install val3dity on my ubuntu 18.04. During installation I followed from https://github.com/tudelft3d/val3dity, an error occured on the line:

```
$ cmake . -DWITH_Eigen3=ON
```

The error was:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES GMP_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I myself is still a beginner in Linux. I wrote every steps I have done so far. You can check my steps from here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Me9DCAbEIsx6SCAQn6GGZGR6TxRta1X2pmtqb-jX0oM/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help what have I done incorrectly? And how can I solve my problem, please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide your steps **as text** in your question post. If possible, do not link to build steps on external site.

Comment: Is GMP installed on your system? e.g. `apt-get install libgmp10 libgmp-dev`

Comment: You will probably also have to install mpfr

Comment: Thank you squareskittles for the gmp install line, also thank you mgimeno for your info to install mpfr. These are really useful info for me. Thank you very much, your solutions made my problem solved, went forward, until I met a new problem. 

Now I am facing a new problem, still on the same command line:

Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least
  version "1.48")

Not sure why I got this, since I installed Boost already. But I believe, this will be a new topic. Anyway, thank you very much for you guys.